# Mocking a Camel Batch Consumer

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I am writing unit tests to test that the routes I have defined in my Spring DSL actually do what i expect them to do

The route I am currently trying to test reads files from a directory and aggregates them.

I let the aggregator know when it is time for it to do its work by using the `completionFromBatchConsumer="true"` property on the Aggregator element in the DSL. This works fine when I am actually retrieving files from a file system.

In my unit test I want to trigger the route without going to the file system, so I have been experimenting by doing `replaceFromWith("direct:start");` and setting that as the default template endpoint Uri. This works to an extent, but I never see my Aggregator get called - I'm assuming this is because it is never informed by the `from` endpoint that the batch has completed.

How can I get the aggregator to recognise that there is work to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send in a property on the exchange when you send to the direct endpoint that the batch size is.

You need to set http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#BATCH_SIZE to 1.

The logic in the aggregator is here: org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor#isCompleted